# if statement that groups all the statements into one if statement

Tags: iphone, if-statement, cocos2d-iphone, grouping, sprite

how do you make an if statement that groups all the statements into one if statement at the moment I've got 20 or something if statements which isn't very efficient so i was wondering if there was a way to group the sprites so that if any of my sprites go off the top of the screen they reappear on the bottom and vice-versa.

At the moment I've got this; *yellow1,2,3...* being the sprite

```
if (yellow1.position.y-33>=320) {
  yellow1.position = ccp(yellow1.position.x,33);
}
if (yellow1.position.y+33<=0) {
  yellow1.position = ccp(yellow1.position.x,287);
}
if (yellow2.position.y-33>=320) {
  yellow2.position = ccp(yellow2.position.x,33);
}
if (yellow2.position.y+33<=0) {
  yellow2.position = ccp(yellow2.position.x,287);
}
if (yellow3.position.y-33>=320) {
  yellow3.position = ccp(yellow3.position.x,33);
}
if (yellow3.position.y+33<=0) {
  yellow3.position = ccp(yellow3.position.x,287);
}
if (yellow4.position.y-33>=320) {
  yellow4.position = ccp(yellow4.position.x,33);
}
if (yellow4.position.y+33<=0) {
  yellow4.position = ccp(yellow4.position.x,287);
}
if (yellow5.position.y-33>=320) {
  yellow5.position = ccp(yellow5.position.x,33);
}
if (yellow5.position.y+33<=0) {
  yellow5.position = ccp(yellow5.position.x,287);
}
if (yellow6.position.y-33>=320) {
  yellow6.position = ccp(yellow6.position.x,33);
}
if (yellow6.position.y+33<=0) {
  yellow6.position = ccp(yellow6.position.x,287);
}
if (yellow7.position.y-33>=320) {
  yellow7.position = ccp(yellow7.position.x,33);
}
if (yellow7.position.y+33<=0) {
  yellow7.position = ccp(yellow7.position.x,287);
}
if (yellow8.position.y-33>=320) {
  yellow8.position = ccp(yellow8.position.x,33);
}
if (yellow8.position.y+33<=0) {
  yellow8.position = ccp(yellow8.position.x,287);
}
```

here is my loop so far:

```
for (int i=0;i<16 ; i++) {
    if (((CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:i]).position.y-((CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:i]).contentSize.height>320) {
        ((CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:i]).position = ccp(((CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:i]).position.x,37);
    }
    if (((CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:i]).position.y+((CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:i]).contentSize.height<0) {
        ((CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:i]).position = ccp(((CCSprite *)[c1array objectAtIndex:i]).position.x,253);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a loop. But first, you need to structure your data into a sequential data structure, such as an array. Then you will loop over each element in the array.

I am not familiar with iPhone programming, but here's the general psuedocode:

```
// Create the list
const int SPRITE_COUNT = 8;
Sprite[] sprites = new Sprite[SPRITE_COUNT];
for(int i = 0; i < SPRITE_COUNT; ++i)
    sprites[i] = new Sprite();

// Later, check for sprites outside
for(int i = 0; i < SPRITE_COUNT; ++i)
{
    if ((sprites[i].position.y + 33) <= 0)
        ccp(sprite.position.x, 287);
    if ((sprites[i].position.y - 33) >= 320)
        ccp(sprite.position.x, 33);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code don't know why i didn't think about looping it through an array :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put your sprites in an arraylist, and loop through the list. This would mean you are running the same amount of code, but letting the runtime do what its good at, and your code will be much tidier.

Comment: hey dude could you help me out with the iphone way of coding the above example that jdmichal posted i've put the later loop in cctouchmoved i'm just not sure where to put the 'creating a list'. Does it go in the header file or the main file with the super if. Thanks

Comment: i'm getting an error with sprite and sprites and how does the code know which sprites to count, the creating a list bit where do i write the sprite names

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?  You can't actually use Sprite as a data type.  As jdmichal said that is just pseudocode. What you want is likely CCSprite if you are using the latest versions of cocos2d.  You will also want to look at the CCArray class which is supposed to work more efficiently than NSArray.  Do you know how to allocate an NSArray or CCArray?  I don't mean to be rude just based on your wording it seems you might not.

Comment: @Rob Segal - No worries, well i know you allocate an array like this NSArray *sprite = [[NSArray alloc] init]; i'm just confused by the code that he gave with the i's in brackets after sprite and new?, in the create the list bit. Could you help me out with creating the list and the checking the code for the sprite outside is fine i think. thanks

Comment: @Rob Segal, could you help me out?

Comment: Hey sorry for not getting back to you.  Based on your comments sounds like you already know how to solve this problem.  You know how to create a list/array so you just need to dump your sprites into that array and do the checks on the sprites following the pseudo code from jdmichal.  Not sure entirely which line(s) your confused about could you quote them explicitly?

Comment: @Rob Segal, sorry i didn't post back to you when you commented you need to put @(this is where you type the user's name in without brackets) otherwise i will not be notified of your comment.
The lines i am confused about are:
Sprite[] sprites = new Sprite[SPRITE_COUNT];
sprites[i] = new Sprite();

Comment: @Dangermouse Hey again. Sorry for my delayed replies just been really busy lately.  Didn't realize I had to use the "@" syntax to ping you.  Thanks for the tip!  If it's still useful  Sprite[] sprites = new Sprite[SPRITE_COUNT];  is just allocating a new array.  In Objective-C that would be  NSMutableArray* sprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:SPRITE_COUNT]  For the line  sprites[i] = new Sprite()  this is assigning a new sprite to each element in the newly allocated array.  In Objective-C that would be  [sprites insertObject:[[Sprite alloc] init] atIndex:i]  Hope that all helps!

Comment: @Rob Segal,no problem, thanks, i've edited my code in the question to show the loop that I have at the moment as it does not work.